# Tab bar not responsive after one of its view contrllers calls: presentViewController and dismissViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I'm transitioning to iOS7 and encountering a problem where my tab bar becomes unresponsive (clicks on tabs not doing anything). The problem occurs after one of the view controllers of the tab bar controller, calls presentViewController, and then later dismissViewController is called. Then the tabs become unresponsive but are visible on the screen.

**Details:** 
appdelegate has a uitabbarcontroller configured via XIB and then calls
[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController]; in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Ok so everything is fine at this point, I have a tab bar with 4 viewcontrollers and I can switch between them clicking the tabs.

**Adding a sub nav:**
One of the tabs has a table view, and when i click a row there, that view controller (showing the table) presents a UINavigationController using: [self presentViewController:subNav animated:NO completion:nil];

So this is fine as well, the new nav controller covers up the tabs as it is supposed to and I push other view controllers on that.

**Problem:**
Later on I call [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]; (I've tried calling this in one of the view controllers shown by the sub nav as well as via a reference to the view controller that first called presentViewController). Purpose is to get back to the original view with the tabs showing.

This works, the sub nav disappears and the Tab view is visible along with the view controller showing that table whose row was clicked, but now none of the tabs at the bottom are responsive to clicks.

So I have no idea what the cause of this is. I don't have this issue in iOS6 version, but there I was using presentModalViewController instead. Help.

**UPDATE: Solved (sort of)**
Ok so I got my tabs working again but not sure what was going on before. So in the non-working code, I did this to get back to my tabs and the original view controller (one of the tabs):

```
UIViewController *viewC=[[self navigationController].viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        if(viewC ==nil) NSLog(@"ViewC is nil");
        [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        FirstViewController *firstV=viewC.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.target;
        if(firstV==nil) NSLog(@"FirstV is nil");
        if(firstV!=nil && [firstV respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissNav)]) [firstV dismissNav];
```

So that is a really hacky way of getting a reference to that first view controller and then calling 'dismissNav' method on it which then calls dismissViewControllerAnimated. So none of that is needed because I can just call dismissViewContrllerAnimated from the "bottom" view controller.

Replaced the above code with this in the 'bottom' view controller:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now the tabs work when they are shown again.

Comment: you are adding view controllers or the navigation controllers to the tabbarcontroller?

Comment: @NitinAlabur The tabbarcontroller has 4 view controllers (in its viewcontroller property). One of those view controllers, then presents a UINavigationController using the presentViewController method.

Comment: so you are not adding instances of uinavigationcontroller as view controllers to the tabs?

Comment: No, I'm presenting a single UINavigationControler by calling presentViewController which is called from one of the view controllers of the tab bar controller.

Comment: Anyway I've found a solution, but not root cause. I'll post an edit to my question.